# Can't delete an event in iMovie because 'the library must contain at least one event'

Tags: imovie

When I try to delete an event in iMovie it tells me, 'the library must contain at least one event.' I have made so many events just to try to delete this one and yet the same message appears.

Answer (score 2):

If it's the only event in a project, you can't delete it, because you can't delete the last event in a project, regardless of how many events you have in other projects. Instead, delete the entire project.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do to delete it if your having problems is delete all the video inside of the project go out of it, and it should say 0s. Then delete the project itself this should solve the problem.

Comment: I am not following your train of thought here, can you explain?